# How to fix "Missing body length in response to SWE request"

Tags: soapui, ibm-datapower, wsdl.exe

I'm getting this exception Missing body length in response to SWE request"  when i was invoking the backend WSP service in SOAPui using Endpoint Explorer option. When i was hitting the backend service directly I'm getting response but through DP FSH I'm not getting response. I checked in logs - Showing "Couldn't establish backend connection". I validated the WSDL. Still didn't find the solution.

Can anyone please help on this issue to fix.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Couldn't establish backend connection` means the WSP is not able to connect to the backend service. You should check that the network is open between the DP instance and the backend service.
You can use the TCP Connection test from the default domain to verify you can connect to the host and port.
Check any certificate, authentication as well. Note that DP by default verify certificates so you need to add any Public key used as a Crypto Certificate in the WSP.
Also check the systems log as there is normally more information prior to the final error that can help you troubleshoot why the DB instance can't access the backend service.

Comment: I tried TCP Connection Test- connection is getting refused and their is no authentication for WSP. I even tried to telnet the IP address and port from command prompt but still same.

Comment: Then something in the network is blocking the access. You need to make sure that you can connect using TCP Connection test from DP to your backend, else it won't work...